# Batch Command for Renaming files in folders

Tags: batch-file, file-rename, batch-rename

Just wondering if anyone can help me. Normally I'm pretty got at finding some code I need an to manipulate it but horrible if I have to start from scratch.

I'm a teacher and want to have all the files labelled consistently as I have to send them off.

What I want to know is there a way to write a batch file to do the following:

I have a subject folder and in each subject folder I have the students name, booklet they are doing in a folder and then there is the file either a .doc or .docx.

I want the batch file to rename the file to what ever it was to Subject_Book#_Name.doc or .docx

My Documents/Subject/Student/Book 1/*.doc*

```
\Math A\Jim Book\Book 1 Addition\Addition Booklet.docx 
\Math A\Jim Book\Book 2 Subtraction\Subtraction Booklet.docx
Into
\Math A\Jim Book\Book 1 Addition\Math A_Addition Booklet_Jim Book.docx 
\Math A\Jim Book\Book 2 Subtraction\Math A_Subtraction Booklet_Jim Book.docx
```

```
\Math A\Frank Sims\Book 1 Addition\Addition Booklet.docx 
\Math A\Frank Sims\Book 2 Subtraction\Subtraction Booklet.docx 
Into
\Math A\Frank Sims\Book 1 Addition\Math A_Addition Booklet_Frank Sims.docx 
\Math A\Frank Sims\Book 2 Subtraction\Math A_Subtraction Booklet_Frank Sims.docx
```

Now I don't mind if I have to copy the bat file into each folder of if some amazing person can help me out and have it in the main subject folder.

I did see something like this somewhere else, but this would still take a lot of time.

````
title Rename Bat
echo This bat must be in the folder that 
echo contains the files to be renamed.
echo Enter File Name
set /p old=
echo Enter New Name
set /p new=
ren "%old%" "%new%"
echo Done
pause```
````

Comment: Could you add two example folder listings for a couple of imaginary students to your post (show the before listing and the desired after listing). Include all relevant folder paths and files from `My Documents` downwards.

Comment: Math A\Jim Book\Book 1 Addition\Addition Booklet.docx
Math A\Jim Book\Book 2 Subtraction\Subtraction Booklet.docx

Math A\Frank Sims\Book 1 Addition\Addition Booklet.docx
Math A\Frank Sims\Book 2 Subtraction\Subtraction Booklet.docx

Comment: So, Frank Sim's Addition Booklet would be renamed to `Math A_Book 1_Frank Sims.docx`?

Comment: Yeah that is it. I also put it in the main post to make it easier to see. First time using this

Comment: PS I'd recommend zipping the entire top-level folder and storing somewhere safely before you try out any proposed solutions. I'm sure you were going to anyway.

Comment: Thank you for that. I've tried running the bat file on a copy of the folder but I get "The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 1):

***As @jarmod mentions in the comments: Keep a safe copy of your original files before you run this operation!  You need a backup just in case.***

This should do it if you run it from within your main directory.  It'll iterate over all matching files in the subdirectories and copy into the current (main) directory.

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "Pattern=\"
Set "Replace=_"
set "RemovePath=!CD:%Pattern%=%Replace%!_"

For /r %%# in ("*.doc?") Do (
    Set "File=%%~f#"
    set "trimfile=!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
    set "trimfile=!trimfile:%RemovePath%=% %!"

    REM If you remove "echo" from the next line, the copy will happen
    echo copy "!File!" "!trimfile!"
)

Pause
```

What it does:

1. Sets a few patterns for replacement. I.e., you want to replace backslash `\` with underscore `_`.
2. Capture the current directory so we can replace it in the filename later.
3. Iterate over all matching files using the full path, and replace the `\` in the path with `_`.
4. Remove the path from the resulting string, since we only want to start the new filename w/the next-level directory name.
5. Echo the command that'll run once you remove the `echo` keyword.*

*Note: The most important line is "disabled" with an `echo` command for you to run safely.  If it looks good to you, remove the word `echo`, and the `copy` operation will happen.*

Comment: Thank you both for that. I've tried running the bat file on a copy of the folder but I get "The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: Provide the full path to one of your files.  Whole thing, drive letter and all.  Also indicate how you're attempting to run what I've provided. I assume you're copying the code above into a batch file, saving that batch file in the main directory at the root of your files, and running it from the command line.

Comment: D:\mligh7\My Documents\1. Class\Class\LSK\Jim Book\Book 1 WHS\Safety Assessment 2020.V1.Final.docx

I have tried running the bat file while located in the LSK folder and Class folder but still no difference. Yeah copied it in to a batch file and from command prompt. Some of my students have also done weird stuff and put (1) into the file name if that makes a difference as well.

Comment: I think you should put some `echo` statements after each line in the loop that logs the variable that was set in the previous statement. That's about the only way I know to see if there's a specific filename it's failing on. But I tested several strange ones w/out issue. You haven't said where in the process you get the error, so I can't tell if it iterates several files or none at all before failing.  More details are better.

Comment: Set "File=%~f#"
 set "trimfile=!File:\=_!"
 set "trimfile=!trimfile:D:_mligh7_My Documents_1. Class_LSK_=!"
 copy !File! !trimfile!

So what I can see it isn't getting to the sub folder that it is needing it is only getting as far as the folder that it is located in

Answer (score 0):

An overworked underappreciated teacher!

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ( 
 'dir /s /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.doc" "%sourcedir%\*.docx" '
 ) DO for %%w in ("%%~dpa.") do for %%g in ("%%~dpw.") do for %%q in ("%%~dpg.") do ECHO REN "%%a" "%%~nxq_%%~na_%%~nxg%%~xa"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.

Greek?

No, Sanskrit.

Primarily, take a `dir` listing in `/b` basic form, `/s` with subdirectories, `/a-d` but no matching directorynames of the two filemasks.

Process the resultant list, ignoring the default delimiters (`"delims="`) to `%%a`and then take the `D`rive and `P`ath of `%%a` (`%%~dpa`) and append `.`, which evaluates to the parent directory name without the trailing backslash. This appears to be a filename, so `%%~dpw` is the grandparent directoryname and `%%~dpq` the great-grandparent directoryname.

And then all we need to do is rename the filename in `%%a` to the ggp-`N`ame and e`X`tension (`%%~nxq`) *underscore* name of the original file (`%%~na`) *underscore* grandparent-`N`ame and e`X`tension (`%%~nxg`) e`X`tension of the original file (`%%~xa`)

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Caution: This is a once-only operation, unless you really want filenames like `\Math A\Jim Book\Book 2 Subtraction\Math A_Math A_Subtraction Booklet_Jim Book_Jim Book.docx`
 then `\Math A\Jim Book\Book 2 Subtraction\Math A_Math A_Math A_Subtraction Booklet_Jim Book_Jim Book_Jim Book.docx`
...

To run the batch, all you need to do is to execute `'d:\wherever\you put\thisbatch"` or if you put `thisbatch.bat` in a directory which is an element of your `path` then just `thisbatch` will suffice.

If you set `sourcedir` to `.` (that is, a single full stop) then the batch will be executed from whatever is your current directory.